# Jenkins running script file

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a Jenkins Pipeline that runs a script file.

I have tested the script outside of Jenkins and it runs perfectly but when I try to run it as part of the pipeline I get the following error:

```
/maint/git-branches.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
branches=()
eval "$(git for-each-ref --shell --format='branches+=(%(refname))' refs/heads/)"
for branch in "${branches[@]}"; do
   echo "${branch##*/}"
done
```

And my pipeline stage is:

```
stage ('Fetching Branches') {
          steps {
            script {
              def branchcollection = sh (script: "sh maint/git-branches.sh", returnStdout: true).trim()
              BRANCH = input message: 'Choose branch to pull from', ok: 'Ok', parameters: [choice(name: 'BRANCH', choices: "${branchCollection}", description: '')]
            }
          }
        }
```

All the `')'` brackets match up so there's no loose ones anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline code is running `git-branches.sh` explicitly with `sh`.  On some systems `sh` is not Bash, and does not support Bash-specific features.  In this case it looks like `sh` does not support arrays.  Try modifying the pipeline code to `... "bash maint/git-branches.sh"...`.